# Solution of second order ODE $y''+(ax+b)y'+cy=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve second order ODE
$$
y''+(ax+b)y'+cy=0
$$

Is there any technique I can apply to solve this equation other than power series method?

I tried using Fourier Transform, but the solution is super ugly...

Comment: [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Comment: Fourier transform is similar to Laplace transform, and it doesn't give "nice" solution.

Comment: Yes well you made the edit to your post _after_ I made the comment. Also you asked for a method on how to solve the problem, I gave you an answer. You should specify your ICs as well.

Comment: Then, any other methods besides LT, FT?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function
Have a look at the section ''Other equations''

Comment: Confluent hypergeometric function! that's what I got!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple writes these solutions in various ways.  In terms of Kummer M and U functions.  Or in terms of Whittaker M and W functions.  Or in terms of hypergeometric ${}_1F_1$ functions.  Or in terms of Laguerre L functions.

So I'm guessing the solutions are usually not elementary functions.

Comment: That's what I got. hypergeometric $_1F_1$ functions. So... maybe no elementary functions... well okay. at least I know where to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try method of variation of parameters ?

Comment: This is an implied answer to the stated question "Is there any technique I can apply to solve this equation other than power series method." This response would be better if flushed out with more detail showing that this method actually works in this case, but it is an answer.

Comment: To use variation of parameters, one has to know $y_1$ and $y_2$, am I correct? Also, variation of parameters is used for nonhomogeneous equation.

Comment: the thing is I want to help but I'm less than 50 rep so I can't comment thanks @RoryDaulton